# `shell.nix` to manually cross-compile a project for `mips-linux-gnu`

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, apple-m1, nix, nix-shell

## motivation

I have a set of steps to build a cross-compiled project (https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64). These steps require e.g. `binutils` targeting a MIPS platform like e.g. `mips-linux-gnu`. (Others like `mips64-elf` or `mips64-linux-gnu` are allegedly also supported by this project.)

-> I want to make a `shell.nix` file that, under `nix-shell` (or `nix shell`), generates an environment with cross-targeting `binutils` executables.

One more note: I am compiling on an M1 mac. However the project doesn't support building from `aarm64-darwin`, so I'm using `x86_64-darwin` as the build platform under the Rosetta2 compatibility layer.

## attempt

I wrote a `shell.nix` like so:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {
    # https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-cross-usage
    localSystem = (import <nixpkgs/lib>).systems.examples.x86_64-darwin;
    crossSystem = (import <nixpkgs/lib>).systems.examples.mips-linux-gnu;
  }
}:

pkgs.mkShell {
  # stuff I want at build-time
  # -> package host = project build
  # -> package target = project host
  # pulled from https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64#step-1-install-dependencies-1
  nativeBuildInputs = [
    # doesn't compile code -> no target
    pkgs.gnumake42
    pkgs.coreutils
    pkgs.pkg-config
    
    # compiles -> target = mips-linux-gnu
    pkgs.binutils
  ];

  shellHook = ''
    # some other setup commands...
  '';
}
```

Running `nix-shell` and trying to use any of the dependencies (e.g., `make`) generates an error like `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. It seems like all the binaries are built to *run* on mips, not to *build for* mips.

I also tried to put these dependencies in `buildInputs` instead. Running the project build then generates the error

```
ld: archive has no table of contents file 'audiofile/libaudiofile.a' for architecture x86_64
```

Imo, this conversely makes it sound like the *target* for `mips-unknown-linux-gnu-ld` is `x86_64`, and NOT `mips`.

## question

How do I rewrite this `shell.nix` file to specify packages that run on `x86_64-darwin`, and build for the target `mips-linux-gnu`?

## EDIT: more info

I opened up a `nix repl` to check what build/host/target my shell would generate:

```
nix-repl> pkgs = import <nixpkgs> { localSystem = (import <nixpkgs/lib>).systems.examples.x86_64-darwin; crossSystem = (import <nixpkgs/lib>).systems.examples.mips-linux-gnu; }

nix-repl> pkgs.stdenv.buildPlatform.config
"x86_64-apple-darwin"

nix-repl> pkgs.stdenv.hostPlatform.config
"mips-unknown-linux-gnu"

nix-repl> pkgs.stdenv.targetPlatform.config
"mips-unknown-linux-gnu"
```

It looks like my *build* platform is `x86_64-darwin`, and my *host and target* platforms are both `mips-linux`. This sounds right; I am using `x86_64-darwin` to *build* this project, and the resulting ROM *runs on* `mips`. (It doesn't generate other code, so the target is irrelevant.)

But `nix-shell` is used for development; when you run `nix-shell derivation.nix`, it drops you into the *build sequence* for the derivation. Thus the environment is on the *build platform*, right? But it seems here like `nix-shell shell.nix` is generating a *host-platform environment*. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! There's a couple things that were going on here, as I now understand it:

- the `audiofile/libaudiofile.a` error was an issue with the project's makefile (which doesn't pose issues when building with other package management tools for some reason...?). I modified the project itself to fix this
- basically *all* of these dependencies (minus one) are provided by default. the only dependency I really needed was `gnumake42`, because the version of the default `make` is incompatible with this project
- the `gnumake42` dependency needed to be in `depsBuildBuild`. `depsBuildHost` (a.k.a. `nativeBuildInputs`) didn't work, not sure why
- there's allegedly [a nix issue](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Cross_Compiling#:%7E:text=the%20examples%20above%20do%20not%20work%20as%20is%20with%20build%20dependencies%20(nativebuildinputs).%20) when cross-compiling via specifying `pkgs {crossSystem = ...}`. the "solution" is to use `callPackage`, though I'm not exactly sure why this fixes the issue
- I thought I needed to set the local system to `x86_64-darwin` for project compatibility, but it turns out removing this to use the default `aarm64-darwin` platform works fine too (lesson: sometimes the community doesn't know best, and there's no harm in experimenting to validate what they say!)

Here's the resulting `shell.nix` file, which I can use to correctly build my desired project:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {
    # https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-cross-usage
    crossSystem = (import <nixpkgs/lib>).systems.examples.mips-linux-gnu;
  }
}:

pkgs.callPackage
  ({ mkShell
   , gnumake42
   }: mkShell {
    # pulled from https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64#step-1-install-dependencies-1
    depsBuildBuild = [
      gnumake42 # v4.4 breaks the build!
    ];

    shellHook = ''
      # same setup code as before
      # ...
    '';
  })
{ }
```